# Discord.py seems not able to load Cog

Tags: python, discord, discord.py

I'm trying to write a basic bot but it seems that the bot doesn't want to load my Cog, which only contains one simple command `test`.

When I tried to call the command both in the bot's DM and in a server that the bot has joined, nothing happens. Here is the bot's log

```
(discord) ~/source/bot » python main.py                                                                                              
2022-12-16 14:46:47 INFO     discord.client logging in using static token
2022-12-16 14:46:49 INFO     discord.gateway Shard ID None has connected to Gateway (Session ID: XXX).
2022-12-16 14:46:51 INFO     root Bot is ready
2022-12-16 14:46:51 INFO     root Setup function called    <-- cog seems to be loaded, but it's not
2022-12-16 14:46:56 INFO     root Message received: %test  <-- when i sent the command via bot's DM
```

main.py

```py
intents = discord.Intents.all()
TOKEN = "XXX"

bot = commands.Bot(command_prefix="%", intents=intents)
logger = logging.StreamHandler(stream=sys.stdout)

@bot.event
async def on_ready():
  logging.info("Bot is ready")
  await bot.load_extension("mycog")

@bot.event
async def on_message(ctx):
  logging.info("Message received: %s", ctx.content)

async def main():
  utils.setup_logging(handler=logger)
  await bot.start(token=TOKEN)

asyncio.run(main())
```

mycog.py

```py
class MyCog(commands.Cog):
  def __init__(self, bot: commands.Bot):
    self.bot = bot
    self.count = 0
  
  @commands.command(name="test")
  async def test(self, ctx):
    # It should log when called, but this isn't the case at the moment
    logging.info("Test function called")
    await ctx.send("Pong!")

async def setup(bot: commands.Bot):
  await bot.add_cog(MyCog(bot))
  logging.info("Setup function called")
```

I also tried to place the `bot.load_extension` call inside `main` before `bot.start` but it didn't work either.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The cog is loaded, but the reason that it is not responding is because you override the default `on_message` event, so the bot won't process the commands.

You can simply fix this by using `bot.listen` instead of `bot.event`, so it won't override the default one. Like this:

```py
@bot.listen()
async def on_message(message):
    ...
```

Or by using the `bot.process_commands` to make the bot process the commands. Like this:

```py
@bot.event
async def on_message(message):
    ...
    await bot.process_commands(message)
```

You can look at this [FAQ](https://discordpy.readthedocs.io/en/stable/faq.html#why-does-on-message-make-my-commands-stop-working) from discord.py for more information.

Comment: This is definitely the answer. Thank you very much!